# Remove edges from matplotlib chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a question regarding removing edges from charts generated using `matplotlib` for Python. What I would like to create is horizontal bar chart where only bars can be seen. For generating chart I am using following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
top_10.plot(kind="barh", ax=ax, color=["#dd4937"])
ax.axis("off")
ax.legend().set_visible(False)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.set_facecolor('red')
fig.savefig(template_dir + "/top_10_chart.png", transparent=True)
```

It almost creates why I require, but there is an space between edge of exported .png and first bar (picture below - added edge box just to show what I would like to achieve). What I would like to achieve is that first bar is on the edge of picture. I presume reason is that axes is nested in figure - can this be changed or for example remove axis (as currently they are only invisibe)?

[image]

Thank you and best regards

Comment: You'd use  `fig.subplots_adjust(right=1)` to have the right side of the axes sit tight against the figure boundary.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest As he only wants the top bar to be near the top-edge, wouldn't it be more correct to use `top` parameter ?

Comment: *"that first bar is on the edge of picture"* can mean just anything; so yes, maybe they mean `top=1`, but it's not clear from the question.

Comment: That did the trick, was not away of possible subplot adjusts. Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting answer here in case it comes in handy to someone.

As both ImportanceOfBeingErnest and IMCoins pointed out, there is actually an option to adjust figure. Only thing that I have added to code is following line:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(top=1, bottom=0)
```

Best regards